# Are non-metallic in-use covers acceptable according to NEC 2011?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Our village goes by the NEC 2011 (they have not updated to current code). Can you use non metallic in-use in Cook County, Illinois, or do i have to use the metal ones?

I looked at 2011 NEC 409.9 A. However when I spoke to the village building inspector he said I could. Hard to reach our electrical inspector and hopefully someone will know.

Comment: I tweaked your question a bit. Local code questions are [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but national code questions are usually fine.

Comment: I've never seen a metallic cover.

Comment: @Harper -- metal while in use covers are a thing -- see the Taymac MX3200 and friends for an example

Comment: @Harper metal in use covers is what i meant..sorrt

Comment: Thank u isherwood--didnt know about local code discussion versus nec.